# Advanced Mail Rule

Tags: mail.app, mail-rules

I want to write a rule like that does the following:

```
act on
    all messages from contacts that are in my address book
do
    move it to the folder <known>
except
    if another rule matches
```

Optimally I would like to provide a list of rules to match. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Make the last two rules in your Mail rules list the following:

```
If Sender is not in my Address Book,
Stop evaluating rules
```

[image]
then

```
If Sender is in my Address Book,
Move message to mailbox ___
```

[image]